# slow query even with the index on large table

Tags: mysql

I am performing a simple select query to extract username from table logs(containing 54864 rows).
It took about 7.836s to retrieve data.
How can I speed up the performace???

```
SELECT username FROM `logs`
WHERE 
logs.branch=1 
and
logs.added_on > '2016-11-27 00:00:00'
```

On describing table,

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username          | char(255)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fullname          | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| package           | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| prev_expiry       | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recharged_upto    | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_option    | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| amount            | float(14,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| branch            | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| added_by          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| added_on          | datetime    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| remark            | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_mode      | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recharge_duration | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_number    | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cheque_no         | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bank_name         | char(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| verify_by_ac      | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| adjusted_days     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| adjustment_note   | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
20 rows in set
```

On explaining query,

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | type | possible_keys               | key          | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs                     | ref  | branch_index,added_on_index | branch_index | 5       | const |   37 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set
```

updated:: explaing query after adding composite index(branch_added_index )

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | type | possible_keys                                  | key          | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logs                     | ref  | branch_index,added_on_index,branch_added_index | branch_index | 5       | const |   37 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a composite key on `branch,added_on` so you cover all the WHERE conditions since you use AND.

`ALTER TABLE logs ADD KEY(branch,added_on)`

This should be much faster,also you can drop the `branch_index` key since the above index can replace it.You only return 37 rows from 54000 so the cardinality is OK.

```
ALTER TABLE logs DROP INDEX `branch_index`;
```

Or you can use index hints

```
SELECT username FROM `logs` USE INDEX (branch_added_index)  WHERE 
logs.branch=1 
and
logs.added_on > '2016-11-27 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I have created the composite index as you suggested but still query execution time is not improved

Comment: @kamalrumba Add the new explain and drop the old index

Comment: @kamalrumba From the new explain I see the query still uses the old index.Just drop it

Comment: I have dropped the index as you suggested and query execution time improved considerably. Can you please explain why separately created indexes on the same column is slower then the composited index.

Comment: @kamalrumba In short, the new index has better cardinality, it can take into account both conditions at the same time while the old index selected all logs.branch=1  and after that it scanned the other column.

Answer (score 2):

if your table's existing index is already used for other queries try adding new composite index like below
`create index <indexname> on logs(branch,added_on)`

Comment: I think we've got the message

Answer (score 1):

create a composite index on 2 fields (branch, added_on) like:

```
ALTER TABLE `logs` ADD KEY idx_branch_added (branch, added_on);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be even faster, because it is "covering":

```
INDEX(branch, added_on, username) -- in exactly that order.
```

(And drop any indexes that are prefixes of this.)

[*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

"Cardinality" is rarely of importance.  And `EXPLAIN` often gets the value wrong.

The `EXPLAIN` shows `5` for the size of `branch` -- does it really need to be `NULLable`?  Will you have 2 billion branches?  Consider using something smaller, such as the 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL` (values 0..255).

Also, shrink the `255` to something reasonable.

When describing a table, please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive.  It might help to know the Engine, Charset, etc.